# Altium: Error on PCB Footprint Updating

Tags: altium

I am using Altium 14.1.5

I made a change to a footprint in a non-integrated library and then wanted to update my PCB with the new footprint and it is not updating properly. I may be doing something wrong.

Here is the scenario: the part is on the bottom side (all silk, pads, etc). When I go to the Tools>Update PCB With Current Footprint and click ok with all the boxes checked

[image: Image of the boxes checked in the Update PCB With Current Footprint dialog box]

my footprint on the PCB rotates 180 degrees and the silk is now on the topside (pads and everything else stays on the bottom). However, when I look at the part information nothing has changed, not even the rotation.

**Properties Before:**
[image: Image of the properties before the part update]

**Properties After:**
[image: Image of the properties after the part update]
*I erased some information due to confidentiality.*

I am not sure why this is happening. Is it a bug that used to be in the in the older version of Altium?

I am adding a pic of the PcbLib footprint and the before and after of what I am trying to explain.

**PcbLib:**
[image: Image of the part in the PcbLib]

**PCB Before:**
[image: Image of PCB before the part update]

**PCB After:**
[image: Image of PCB after the part update]

Comment: The image you shared shows the designator is on the bottom overlay layer after the change, same as before. I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Pictures of the actual part footprint before and after would be helpful

Comment: Also why are you using such an old version of Altium? Upgrades are free.

Comment: I added a before and after image and the PcbLib image to show what is going on.  As it can be seen, the silk jumps to the top overlay even though it should stay on the bottom overlay as MOD3 does. Also, I was not aware that upgrades are free. I thought they costed several thousand dollars. Please provide a link that would indicate they are free.

Comment: While I am still interested if anyone knows why the above situation happened, I decided to just delete the part from the PCB and re import it back to the board as time was a constraint. If anyone has any idea as to why the static silk flipped, as well as the part rotating but nothing indicates that in the properties, it would be greatly appreciated.